# Are players allowed to show one card mid-game?

Tags: rules, etiquette

Is there any rule forcing players not to show their cards before showdown, while a hand is being played? Can players talk aloud about their hands? That is, not a folded hand.

What would happen if a player folds a hand and start talking about his hand?

Answer (score 2):

Players must not talk about their folded holdings while the hand is still ongoing! Indeed, the polite thing to do is to shut up after you fold.

There are no universal rules about what to do, and most venues will be tolerant. But if the behaiviour persists, you could be punished in various ways, from forcing you to sittout for a few rounds to immediate disqualification in tournaments, or simply a ban for cash games

Answer (score 1):

Similar question [here](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/showing-hand-before-call).

> You need to be careful with this. In some casinos this is perfectly allowed while in others, like most here in Vancouver, your hand is automatically dead the second you show it to another player, regardless of how many people are still in the hand.

Basically in some casinos you mustn't reveal cards at all, while in some other casinos this is fine. If you're not having the last word, this is definitely forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

It’s dependent on the house-rules. But my guess is that most casinos won’t allow it. Also, this might also be a situational question.

It might make a huge difference if you show the card(s) in a multiway pot when you have people behind you to act, or showing it to your opponent heads up in order to get a read while making a river-bet decision (call/fold). In Multiway situations with people behind to act it’s definitely considered bad etiquette, since this could influence players to make moves against others that they wouldn’t make without that information.

Here’s a video from Doug Polk explaining this more in detail based on a hand played at the WSOP 2018. In this video, the cards aren’t even shown. Sometimes, talking is just as bad etiquette as showing the holecards.
[Youtube - Why Everyone Is Freaking Out About this Phil Hellmuth Incident (2018 WSOP)](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cnZf0mafZ3k)